# PHP logout with many subdomains

Tags: php, session, subdomain, logout

Why when I logout user at www.mywebsite.com, his session still exist at mywebsite.com (without www)?
I tried to put my website just at mywebsite.com, but I want to build a SaaS service, so the problem is real.
My logout code:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  session_unset();
  header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Do I need to logout him at every subdomain on my website? How to fix it?

Comment: session_unset just clears out the session for usage. The session is still on the users computer. Note that by using session_unset, the variable still exists. session_unset just remove all session variables. it does not destroy the session....so the session would still be active.

Comment: But I already tried to add session_destroy() and nothing better happened

Comment: If your description is accurate (it is very incomplete and even then highly suspicious) then the only explanation is that you've got some multiple sessions connected by some session propogation or SSO mechanism you've not told us about.

Comment: No, I am using the same variables everywhere. There is no sign-up mechanism, because there is no need to ...yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
session_destroy();
```

It destroys all data registered to a session.

Comment: How are you setting and checking the session. Please post the code.

Comment: $_SESSION['NAME'] = $name;
                  $_SESSION['PASS'] = $password;
                  $_SESSION['id'] = $user_id;

Comment: How are you checking the session ? Code Please